# Overlay Layout crashes in Android O

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I use this code to show the overlay layout in my app. In android 8.0 "Oreo" it crashes

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams playerParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

I found that this TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR is deprecated in O. Is there any other way to show the layout.

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing the same issue the **TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR** is Deprecated in oreo So if we have to use that we need to do this

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
} else {
    params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
}
```

You can try this out.

Comment: Welcome, I was also facing the same issues before few days.

Comment: Try this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48782715/android-disable-and-enable-to-pulling-the-status-bar-programmatically-for-api-1

Comment: this is not helping to show the layout overlock screen. please suggest.

Comment: have you given permission of wakeup lock