# Android: Disable and enable to pulling the status bar programmatically for API 19

Tags: android, statusbar

I already done do to hide the status bar, but unfortunately I didn't found the way to display it back once its already hide. I did so many workaround but still not success, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8273225/5065755) and [here](https://efransiscus.wordpress.com/2012/04/11/remove-android-status-bar-programmatically/).

**Activity**

```
 WindowManager manager = ((WindowManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE));

 WindowManager.LayoutParams localLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
 localLayoutParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;
 localLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
 localLayoutParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|

 // this is to enable the notification to receive touch events
 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |

 // Draws over status bar
 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN;

 localLayoutParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
 localLayoutParams.height = (int) (50 * getResources()
                .getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity);
 localLayoutParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT;

 customViewGroup view = new customViewGroup(this);
 manager.addView(view, localLayoutParams);
```

**customViewGroup class**

```
class customViewGroup extends ViewGroup {

    public customViewGroup(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

### For Hiding Status Bar on 4.1 or Higher use

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide the status bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
// Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
// status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

### OR

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

### To make Status Bar Visible

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide the status bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
// Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
// status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.show();
```

### OR

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
```

[Refer Immersve View](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html)

[android Exit from full screen mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684440/android-exit-from-full-screen-mode)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I didn't want to make a fullscreen, I want to keep all the the information on status bar. Just want to disable the pulling bar. Sorry for my wrong word in explanation.

Answer (score 3):

I think permanently disable the status bar is difficult. I am also working on the same concept and did lots of R&D and found that below code can be useful. if the user tries to expand the status bar then within a sec it will pull back it and it will work on oreo as well. I have tried on different OS.

```
public class BlockStatusBar { 
Context context
// To keep track of activity's window focus
    boolean currentFocus;
    // To keep track of activity's foreground/background status
    boolean isPaused;

    public Handler collapseNotificationHandler;
    Method collapseStatusBar = null;

    public BlockStatusBar(Context context, boolean isPaused) {
        this.context = context;
        this.isPaused = isPaused;
        collapseNow();
    }

    public void collapseNow() {


        // Initialize 'collapseNotificationHandler'
        if (collapseNotificationHandler == null) {
            collapseNotificationHandler = new Handler();

        }

        // If window focus has been lost && activity is not in a paused state
        // Its a valid check because showing of notification panel
        // steals the focus from current activity's window, but does not
        // 'pause' the activity
        if (!currentFocus && !isPaused) {

            Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // do something
                    try {

                        // Use reflection to trigger a method from 'StatusBarManager'
                        Object statusBarService = context.getSystemService("statusbar");
                        Class<?> statusBarManager = null;

                        try {
                            statusBarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
                        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "" + e.getMessage());
                        }

                        try {

                            // Prior to API 17, the method to call is 'collapse()'
                            // API 17 onwards, the method to call is `collapsePanels()`
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 16) {
                                collapseStatusBar = statusBarManager.getMethod("collapsePanels");
                            } else {
                                collapseStatusBar = statusBarManager.getMethod("collapse");
                            }
                        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "" + e.getMessage());
                        }

                        collapseStatusBar.setAccessible(true);

                        try {
                            collapseStatusBar.invoke(statusBarService);
                        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        // Check if the window focus has been returned
                        // If it hasn'kioskthread been returned, post this Runnable again
                        // Currently, the delay is 100 ms. You can change this
                        // value to suit your needs.
                        if (!currentFocus && !isPaused) {
                            collapseNotificationHandler.postDelayed(this, 100L);

                        }
                        if (!currentFocus && isPaused) {
                            collapseNotificationHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("MSG", "" + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            };
            // Post a Runnable with some delay - currently set to 300 ms
            collapseNotificationHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, 1L);

        }
    }
}
```